# Type error: url is undefined extjs 4 populating combobox

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

I am creating a combo box using extjs 4 in an editable grid (im using extjs 4) and i am using external ajax call to populate it rather than using a extjs proxy, the reason is that i am using the same call for loading other combo boxes. So i thought why not use the same function. Here is the code for store, model, dropdown and ajax call:

```
var drpdwnitems = "";

Ext.define('rStatusRecord', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'code', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'value', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

var dsStatus = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { model: 'rStatusRecord', data: [] });

var timeSelectField_1 = {
     xtype: 'combobox',
     typeAhead: true,
     displayField: 'code',
     valueField: 'value',
     store: dsStatus,
     triggerAction: 'all'

};
```

This field is basically used in grid panel's column for the editing purpose. AJax call is basically returning a string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XHR/Task_TypesCalls.aspx?TL_A=1", 
    error: function() { alert('Error loading document'); },
    success: loadAvailableTasksList
});

function loadAvailableTasksList(contents, status) {
     drpdwnitems = contents.split("!");
     if (status != "success") return;

     var drpdwnitemsind;

     dsStatus.removeAll();
     for (i = 0; i < drpdwnitems.length; i++) {
        drpdwnitemsind = drpdwnitems[i].split(":");
        statusRecord = Ext.create('rStatusRecord', {
          code: drpdwnitemsind[0], //"",
          value: drpdwnitemsind[0]//""
        });

        dsStatus.add(statusRecord);
      } //end of loop
}
```

Now when i edit the field and open the combo box, there is an error 
TypeError: url is undefined
This error is in the file ext-all-debug.js
What my guess is that url config of store is necessary and im not providing it. OR am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryMode

You want to set it to local.